# How to run R in spring mvc application

Tags: r, spring-mvc, ggplot2, data-visualization, rjava

Hi all, hope you doing well, I am able plot in R studio but I am not getting how to display plotted chart in my web application. After trying, I understood that I should run R in my web application for this I used rJava, somehow I manged to perform addition and other calculations but I am not getting how to show the plotted chart (R) in web page. Has anyone shown plotted charts in web application or any sources to implement this.

Calculated Standard deviation using below code

```
private ScriptEngine getScriptEngine() {
        ScriptEngine engine = ENGINE.get();
        if(engine == null) {
            // Create a new ScriptEngine for this thread if one does not exist.
            RenjinScriptEngineFactory factory = new RenjinScriptEngineFactory();
            engine = factory.getScriptEngine();
            ENGINE.set(engine);
        }
        return engine;
    }
    
    
    
    
    ScriptEngine engine = getScriptEngine();
            
        try {
            engine.eval("df <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=(1:10)+rnorm(n=10))");
            engine.eval("print(df)");
            engine.eval("print(lm(y ~ x, df))");
            
            engine.eval("x <- 1:5");
            engine.eval("y <- 6:10");
            engine.eval("print(x)");
            engine.eval("print(y)");
            
            }catch (ScriptException e) {
            throw new ServletException(e);
        }
```

Comment: Could you include an example for the steps that you have tried so far?

Comment: dear @teunbrand updated what I have tried.